# how to get slug dynamically using dynamic API Routes in nextjs 14?

Tags: next.js, routes, next.js14

[i'm trying to get user's-verification token using Dynamic Api Routes using nextjs-14 latest version.
For Users's verification process my Base Route is "/api/auth/verify" in nextjs4 using app router.
now im sending Registration link in user's mail when they are registering themselves, verification links looks like "mywebsite/api/auth/register/token",

in short for different users token will be different like,
"mywebsite/api/auth/register/token1",""mywebsite/api/auth/register/token2",""mywebsite/api/auth/register/token3"
so

how can i get that token which are changing for different users?

my routes are api => register

```
                      login
                      verify
                      \[token\]
```

i want to fetch that changing token param. how can i get in route.js file

i'm not able to log something in this get request. also i'm getting this error while hitting get request in Postmen:

> Error: Page "/api/auth/verify/[token]/route" is missing exported function "generateStaticParams()", which is required with "output: export" config.

i want to  get dynamic token inside this code, how can i get that token here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `next.config.js` You have `output: "export"`. By setting the output to `"export"`, You are telling the Next.js compiler that you need a static assets to deploy to my static hosting I don't have a server to run my app on.

When you do that, you can't generate route handler that depends on the runtime data. You can not generate `/api/auth/verify/{token}` where token is not known at the build time.

If you have a subset of tokens that the compiler can know at the build time, you can provide them you exporting `generateStaticParams`

```js
// app/api/auth/verify/[token]/route.ts

export async function GET(req, {params}) {
  return new Response(`${params.token}-${Math.random().toString()}`)
}

export function generateStaticParams() {
  return [{token: "1"}, {token: "2"}, {token: "3"}, {token: "4"}]
}
```

This solution would not be helpful for your case, verifying users by tokens generated at the runtime, you have to get red of `output: "export"` and deploy to server-less platform of self-host in a Node.js server to achieve this functionality.

Comment: thanks mate, i got token using thuis way :)