# Next.js generateStaticParams not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to use Next.js to write a simple webpage which that lets me select an event from a list and click on it.
Clicking on it should bring me to a new page with the event details, in this case I am only displaying its ID.

I want to build that in order to have static assets but when I run yarn build this is what I get:

```
Error: Page "/event/[eventid]" is missing "generateStaticParams()" so it cannot be used with "output: export" config.
```

This is my next.config.mjs:

```
const nextConfig = {
    output: "export",
};
```

I have also tried adding `dynamicParams = true` but the result is the same.

I have seen in the documentation examples that generateStaticParams is used to fetch some "allowed" values for eventid, but I don't know the list of available events that are available, because they will be added dynamically. I would like the eventid to be a wildcard for any possible input in the URL.

This is the event/[eventid] page.tsx file content:

```
export const dynamicParams = true;
export async function generateStaticParams() {
    return [];
}

export default function AnEvent({ params: { eventid }} : { params: { eventid: number }}) {
    return <div>Event {eventid}</div>;
}
```

This is the event page.tsx file content:

```
import Link from "next/link";

export default function EventList() {
  return <div>
    <Link href="/event/33">Event 33</Link>
    <Link href="/event/28">Event 28</Link>
    <Link href="/event/16">Event 16</Link>
  </div>;
}
```

Note that it does not work even if I add the list of these three static elements to the array returned by generateStaticParams

[image: visual studio file structure and involved page]

Comment: I am using next 14.1.0 in a project created using npx create-next-app@latest --use-yarn

Comment: Does this anser your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/77947700/18079514 ?

Comment: @AhmedAbdelbaset that states that it is impossible in next.js to have dynamic routes the way I need them, and this would be an answer (even though I am able to achieve that in Vue.js, therefore it is not a technological limit but a choice of the framework not to address this point). But I have tried adding some static elements in the array returned by generateStaticParams and still I am not able to build the project